# JWT Verification Failing

Tags: jwt

I am new to JWT tokens. I am able to create and verify JWT in Java (using [JJWT](https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-java-create-verify/)) and even online using following link http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html.

BUT when I try to create JWT using one source and try to validate using another, it always fail. I couldn't successfully generate and validate JWT using 2 different sources. I even tried using http://jwt.io

Can someone help me understand what might be wrong? I believe it should be possible to create JWT using one library and validate using another library considering you are using correct sign algo and secret key.

Comment: Could you post some example tokens you've generated but won't validate, and the key(s)?

Comment: Example, I generated this token "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2p3dC1pZHAuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiJtYWlsdG86bWlrZUBleGFtcGxlLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6ImlkMTIzNDU2IiwidHlwIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9yZWdpc3RlciJ9.5B5OL9aYn6KIlVo8dGBs9_QpQv1b_CYmasw_7Kz3qZ8" using key 616161 (HMAC SHA256) and with link http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html. I can't validate this token at http://jwt.io.

Comment: Add additional information to the question, not a comment that may be missed by those answering. Then delete this comment.

Answer (score 2):

The key input at http://kjur.github.io/jsjws/tool_jwt.html accepts **hex-encoded** values.  The default secret `616161` actually decodes to `aaa`.  Verifying the generated token at http://jwt.io/ using `aaa` as the secret works.

Answer (score 1):

One aspect of JWT that can confuse is that it does not encrypt the data.
It is possible to extract the contents of a JWT including all the fields. The signing of it however allows us to validate that the token was generated/signed with a particular secret and it is this that is used to validate or authenticate.
If that is not the issue then it could well be just the tool/library key encoding as suggested by @frasertweedale - care needs to be taken to encode all the source fields appropriately.